# XML array loop only looping once

Tags: php, domdocument

I'm trying to build an associative array out of data that I'm parsing from a large XML file. The problem is that the array is only outputting one loop. I can't get it to build with all the loops of node in question.

The XML structure is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
    ...
    <property>
        ...
        <images>
            <image id="1">
                <url>https://example.com/image1.jpg</url>
                <title>
                    <en>en_lang_translation</en>
                    <es>es_lang_translation</es>
                    <de>de_lang_translation</de>
                </title>
            </image>
            <image id="2">
                <url>https://example.com/image2.jpg</url>
                <title>
                    <en>en_lang_translation</en>
                    <es>es_lang_translation</es>
                    <de>de_lang_translation</de>
                </title>
            </image>
        </images>
        ...
    </property>
    ...
</root>
```

...and the code I've got so far is as follows:

```
foreach($property->childNodes as $nodename) {

    if($nodename->nodeName == 'images') {

        $imageArray = array();

        foreach($nodename->childNodes as $imageNodes) {

            foreach($imageNodes->childNodes as $imageSubNodes) {

                if($imageSubNodes->nodeName == 'url') {

                    $imageArray['url'] = $imageSubNodes->nodeValue;

                } else if($imageSubNodes->nodeName == 'title') {

                    foreach($imageSubNodes->childNodes as $titleNode) {

                        foreach($titleNode->childNodes as $titleLangNode) {

                            $childs = $titleNode->childNodes;
                            $key = $titleNode->nodeName;

                            foreach ($childs as $p) {

                                $imageArray[$key] = $p->nodeValue;

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Guidance is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You're probably replacing the items everytime instead of creating new ones.

Comment: To test, add `echo  $p->nodeValue;` before `$imageArray[$key] = $p->nodeValue;` it'll display everything. You might need a multilevel array here...

Comment: What's the current output? and add a counter variable to count the loops just in order to make sure it runs 1 time. ($i = 0; prior to the loop, and before the loop end add $i++) after the loop print the $i value.

Comment: Cracked it guys. I was overwriting the array each loop run. Thanks for your help and pointing me in right direction.

Comment: @d1ch0t0my Rather than edit the question to add the solution, post it as answer! Answering your own question is not forbidden (there is even an option to answer the question directly at the "ask a question" page)

Comment: Oops sorry, thanks chade_. Done.

Answer (score 0):

Cracked it. It was the comments below (thanks guys) that pointed me to the solution. I was overwriting the array with each loop run. I went back to the drawing board and simplified the foreach loops as that was really where I went wrong, getting lost in the multiple loops. My fixed code is below:

```
while(is_object($property = $doc->getElementsByTagName("property")->item($i))) {

    foreach($property->childNodes as $nodename) {

        if($nodename->nodeName=='images') {

            foreach($nodename->childNodes as $images) {

                if($images->nodeName == 'image') {
                    //now in each images node - children are image
                    foreach($images->childNodes as $image) {
                        //now in each image node - children are url & title
                        if($image->nodeName == 'url'){
                            $image_url = $image->nodeValue;
                        }
                        if($image->nodeName == 'title'){
                            foreach($image->childNodes as $title) {
                                // now in title node - children en, es, de
                                if($title->nodeName == 'en'){
                                    $title_en = $title->nodeValue;
                                }
                                if($title->nodeName == 'es'){
                                    $title_es = $title->nodeValue;
                                }
                                if($title->nodeName == 'de'){
                                    $title_de = $title->nodeValue;
                                }
                            }
                        }                       
                    }
                }
                $imageArray[] = array('url' => $image_url, 'title_en' => $title_en, 'title_es' => $title_es, 'title_de' => $title_de);
            }

        } 
    }

    $i++;
}
echo '<ul>';
foreach ($imageArray as $key => $value) {
    echo '<li>'.$value['url'].' - '.$value['title_en'].'</li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, consider using **zero** loops, `if` logic, or arrays, only [XSLT](https://www.w3.org/Style/XSL/) to convert your source XML to HTML list items:

**XSLT** *(save as .xsl script, a special well-formed .xml file)*

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="/root">
    <ul>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="property"/>
    </ul>
  </xsl:template>  

  <xsl:template match="property|images">    
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>    
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="image">    
      <li><xsl:value-of select="concat(url, ' - ', title/en)"/></li>
      <li><xsl:value-of select="concat(url, ' - ', title/es)"/></li>
      <li><xsl:value-of select="concat(url, ' - ', title/de)"/></li>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**PHP**

```
// LOAD XML AND XSL SOURCES
$xml = new DOMDocument;
$xml->load('Input.xml');

$xsl = new DOMDocument;
$xsl->load('XSLTScript.xsl');

// CONFIGURE TRANSFORMER
$proc = new XSLTProcessor;
$proc->importStyleSheet($xsl);

// TRANSFORM XML 
$newXML = new DOMDocument;
$newXML = $proc->transformToXML($xml);

echo $newXML;   // <--- STRING OUTPUT

// <ul>
//    <li>https://example.com/image1.jpg - en_lang_translation</li>
//    <li>https://example.com/image1.jpg - es_lang_translation</li>
//    <li>https://example.com/image1.jpg - de_lang_translation</li>
//    <li>https://example.com/image2.jpg - en_lang_translation</li>
//    <li>https://example.com/image2.jpg - es_lang_translation</li>
//    <li>https://example.com/image2.jpg - de_lang_translation</li>
// </ul>
```

Comment: Interesting. I'll take a look at this option, thanks Parfait.